# How can I adjust the column width in a siunitx package?

Tags: siunitx

```
\documentclass[5p,times,sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow, graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[input-ignore={,},input-decimal-markers={.},group-separator={,}]{siunitx}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf,labelsep=newline,skip=.1cm}
\captionsetup{labelsep=space,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=off}

\newcommand{\expo}[1]{$^{#1}$}
\newcommand{\indic}[1]{$_{#1}$}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!t]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Experimental and calculated crystal-field energy levels}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
        l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
        l
        S[table-format=5.0]
        S[table-format=5.0]
        S[table-format=5.0]
        S[table-format=5.0]
        }
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}*{Multiplet} & \multirow{2}*{Stark energy levels} & %
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Experimental Values} & \text{Calculated values} \\
        \cmidrule{3-6}
         & & \text{Matrix host name epilayers} & \text{Matrix host name Nanorods} & \text{Matrix host name} \\
        \midrule
        \multirow{3}*{\expo{2}F\indic{5/2}} & F\indic{7} & 10,000 & 10,000 & 10,000 & 10,000 \\
         & F\indic{6} & 10,000 & 10,000 & 10,000 & 10,000 \\
         & F\indic{5} & 10,000 & 10,000 & 10,000 & 10,000 \\
        \multirow{4}*{\expo{2}F\indic{7/2}} & F\indic{4} & 333 & 333 & 333 & 333 \\
         & F\indic{3} & 111 & 111 & 111 & 111 \\
         & F\indic{2} & 222 & 222 & 222 & 222 \\
         & F\indic{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see the column's headings does not fit to the table. What should I fix to solve this issue?

Comment: With `\multirow` it's not at all clear what rows the two items in the first column refer to. If they were aligned with the first referenced row, it would be much clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is is this you want?

```
\documentclass[5p,times,sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow, graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{showframe} %
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}%
\usepackage{makecell}%
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[input-ignore={,},input-decimal-markers={.},group-separator={,}]{siunitx}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf,labelsep=newline,skip=.1cm}
\captionsetup{labelsep=space,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=off}

\newcommand{\expo}[1]{$^{#1}$}
\newcommand{\indic}[1]{$_{#1}$}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!t]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Experimental and calculated crystal-field energy levels}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
        l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
       c
        S[table-format=5.0]
        S[table-format=5.0]
        S[table-format=5.0]
        S[table-format=5.0]
        }
        \toprule
        \multirow{3}*{Multiplet} & \multirowcell{3}{Stark\\ energy levels} & %
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Experimental Values} & \text{Calculated values} \\
        \cmidrule{3-5}\cmidrule{6-6}
         & & {\makecell{Matrix host name\\ epilayers}} & {\makecell{Matrix host name\\ Nanorods}} & \text{Matrix host name} \\
        \midrule
        \multirow{3}*{\expo{2}F\indic{5/2}} & F\indic{7} & 10,000 & 10,000 & 10,000 & 10,000 \\
         & F\indic{6} & 10,000 & 10,000 & 10,000 & 10,000 \\
         & F\indic{5} & 10,000 & 10,000 & 10,000 & 10,000 \\
        \multirow{4}*{\expo{2}F\indic{7/2}} & F\indic{4} & 333 & 333 & 333 & 333 \\
         & F\indic{3} & 111 & 111 & 111 & 111 \\
         & F\indic{2} & 222 & 222 & 222 & 222 \\
         & F\indic{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]